# how to get selected fields from the index in kibana

Tags: kibana-6

Here I need to fetch the key, value pair of particular index based on the some conditions.

**I need only few fields in that index doc not all fields**

**I need only fields which i given in input.**

```
 GET /_search?&pretty=true&size=3
{
 "query": {

         "query_string": {

           "query": "countryCode:SA AND serviceName:SMS",
           "fields": ["level","cause","to"]
         }
       }    
}
```

**Output:**

```
 {
      "took": 2854,
      "timed_out": false,
      "num_reduce_phases": 4,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 1891,
        "successful": 1891,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 14032,
        "max_score": 8.429943,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "postman-2019.01.21",
            "_type": "syslog",
            "_id": "AWhvN1KDl97BCeGFfgpe",
            "_score": 8.429943,
            "_source": {
              "eId": "346589962",
              "level": "info",
              "prevStatus": "SUCCESS",
              "cause": "SUCCESS",
              "serviceName": "SMS",
              "loggingAction": "SMS_CALLBACK_REPORTS",
              "application": "POSTMAN",
              "countryCode": "SA",
              "client": "CRS",
              "to": "+966572444531",
              "externalServiceName": "gupshupInternationalChannelA",
              "time": "Mon Jan 21 07:02:02 UTC 2019",
              "category": "OTP",
              "dId": "3762647059352507724-309778596902014991",
              "uIdentifier": "2e262115-d09c-4bef-a04b-d0860d064930",
              "epochTime": 1548054122491,
              "status": "DELIVERED",
              "@version": "1",
              "@timestamp": "2019-01-21T07:02:03.124Z",
              "path": "/mnt/logs/logstash",
              "host": "ip-10-20-10-164",
              "type": "syslog"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

this is output i got, but i need only fields which i given in input

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try :

```
POST cars/_search
    {
        "_source": {
            "includes": [ "price_eur", "stk_year" ],
            "excludes": [ "mileage" ]
        },
        "query" : {
            "match" : { "maker" : "audi" }
        }
    }


POST cars/_search?&pretty=true&size=3
    {
        "_source": {
            "includes": [ "price_eur", "stk_year" ],
            "excludes": [ "mileage" ]
        },
        "query" : {
            "match" : { "maker" : "audi" }
        }
    }
```

[image: Kibana Tool]